# Vline - Anyway to prevent vline from "hanging up" after a certain amount of time waiting for the other user to connect?

Tags: vline

I am testing out Vline's API currently and am basically comparing it to OpenTok.  The main issue/difference I am running across is that I would like to have the ability for one side to log in to our system start transmitting audio/video and then just wait for the other party to connect at some point in the future (typically 5-10 minutes max) and have them automatically connect up.  This can be done with OpenTok fairly easily - as they do not have the same concept of "calling" another user - it is really transmitting a stream to a session and users in the session can receive those transmissions.

With Vline - the problem is that after calling startMedia() if no-one answers within about 15 seconds the mediastream seems to automatically stop.  Our goal is to have the first user be able to see themselves in a camera view until the other party connects and then they will see both themselves and the other party.

Is this possible with Vline?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. I went ahead and created a simple example that is available on GitHub: https://github.com/vline/vline-room-example

*NOTE: We are working on a "Room API" that will make this example much simpler.*

Comment: thanks so much Tom!  This is great!  I will try this out - but at first glance of the code it makes perfect sense!  I would give you an up vote but I don't have the rep yet!

Comment: Is there any news on the "Room API"? I didn't see any documentation on the vLine site but would love to use it.